# How to force \tikzexternalize to stop compilation in case of error?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, tikz-external

I have a rather annoying error or rather lack of error when I use \tikzexternalize. Take for example the following code that draws two circles

```
% !TeX program =Xelatex+shell-escape
% !TeX encoding = utf8
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
 
\begin{document}
\tikzsetnextfilename{testExterne} % Nom du fichier de sortie de la figure

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue] (0,0) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get both circles
[image]

Let's modify the code by adding an error that would normally block the compilation (circles)

```
% !TeX program =Xelatex+shell-escape
% !TeX encoding = utf8
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
 
\begin{document}
\tikzsetnextfilename{testExterne} % Nom du fichier de sortie de la figure

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue] (0,0) circles (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

At home (Miktex, compilation with xelatex) the compilation does not stop (there is indeed a fleeting message) and the pdf is inclang.

On such a small example, we can see the error but on a manual of several dozen pages with a large number of drawings this is almost impossible.

I also note that sometimes the correct figures are not recalculated.